# Sci Fi Short Story where astronaut comes back to Earth with virus, in coma, all life dies, he wakes up later and has to nuke earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am pretty sure this is from one of the Annual World's Best SF series in the 1980's, I just can't remember the name of the story. In addition to what I listed above the astronaut figures out an alien invasion is coming and they gave him the virus, he survived because he was put in a hospital in a coma and it was tended by robots. The invading aliens turn off the virus by an elctro magnetic pulse or by making the North and South poles switch, but the astronaut elects himself leader of the world through the computer network and nukes Earth as the alien invasion is landing.